# Undo a CVS commit using IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, cvs

I just committed a bunch (well, 11) of files into our CVS repository with the wrong comment on them.   Is there a way to UNDO this commit so that I can re-commit them with the correct comment?

Alternately, is there a way to forcibly re-commit without going back in and monkeying with each file so that IntelliJ sees the file as "changed"?

Comment: It should be possible with the command line client, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/9153984/104891.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no easy way to roll this back except by using the command line client:  [How to revert to previous commit in CVS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153984/how-to-revert-to-previous-commit-in-cvs)

There is no apparent way to do this in Intellij Idea.