# How can I revert a whole project to an earlier tag in CVS?

Tags: windows, version-control, cvs, wincvs

I have a poject that has thousands of files. I made some changes that affected almost half of the files. the changes included editing existing files and adding new files and directories.

I need to revert all these changes and restore the project to how it was. I have created a tag before doing all this but I am not sure how I can restore the whole project from the tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert to previous commit in CVS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153984/how-to-revert-to-previous-commit-in-cvs)

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately the kind of thing that CVS is particularly not good at.

I do not believe that you can lose the history of your big commit (*) but rather you want to commit the reverse of your original changes (a `revert` in some SCM's terminology).

I recommend using non-CVS tools to determine what needs to be done and then just do the commits in CVS.

- Have two workspaces checked out. One checked out to the branch/HEAD and the other checked out to your tag.
- Create lists of files in each workspace and do the appropriate diffs (not `cvs diff`, just regular `diff` or `comm` or whatever you want for this) to get three lists: files you now need to Add and Delete.
- Do some diffs to find out what files you need to modify.
- `cvs add` the files that need adding. (Not sure if `-kb` is necessary when re-adding a file, probably not, but I'm not certain.)
- `cvs rm` the files that need deleting.
- Copy over the ones that need modifying and `cvs commit -R` them all at once.

If you have a log file that contain the details of your original big commit, you could also use that to create your list of add/delete/modify commands.

(*) Well, you could probably one-by-one use `cvs admin` to remove the new file versions, but I do not think that is advisable at all.