# roll back cvs after committing changes

Tags: cvs, rollback

I have a code that I changed on 6th nov,2017 and then, I committed the changes to cvs and did build cvs update too.

However, Now I want to revert back to the version I had on 5th November, 2017. How can I go about this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to have the old version in your workspace (`cvs update -dPR -D <date> `), or do you mean you want to undo your changes and commit to the server that undoing?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with Perl so I removed that tag.

Comment: If it is the second of my two options you were looking for, you can see my answer to this very recent question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46355167/600360